# Office365 Security Groups Update Time

Tags: sharepoint, security-groups, office365

My organisation is using Office365.
I just created a security group. I called it `Developer Security Group`. I also have a Sharepoint site. All the developers were added to this exchange site. I removed them all from the exchange site and added the security group instead.

In the security group, everyone is added as a member. The security group is added as a member to the site as well.

I believe I have done everything correctly, but nobody has access anymore. Is there an update cycle until it takes effect? How long does it take? Or did I do something wrong?

Edit:
It started working. Took somewhere in the range of 1-3 hours.

Comment: Is the SharePoint site using Windows integrated authentication?

Comment: I honestly don't know. How do I looke this up? We usally sign up using our office365 microsoft logins.